# What is <form:select path> in spring tag used for?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Can someone please tell me what do I need to specify in `<form:select>` path attribute and what it's used for? actually I need to understand how the value of the selected item from the dropdown is passed onto the controller?

Answer (score 38):

Say you have a model (Dog for example), a `Dog` has various attributes:
name
age
breed

if you want to make a simple form for adding/editing a dog, you'd use something that looks like this:

```
<form:form action="/saveDog" modelAttribute="myDog">

    <form:input path="name"></form:input>
    <form:input path="age"></form:input>
    <form:select path="breed">
        <form:options items="${allBreeds}" itemValue="breedId" itemLabel="breedName" />
    </form:select>

</form:form>
```

As you can see, I've chosen the `breed` property to be a `select`, because **I don't want the user to type** whatever breed he want, **I want him to choose from a list** (`allBreeds` in this case, which the controller will pass to the view).

In the `<form:select>` I've used `path` to tell spring that the select has to bind to the `breed` of the `Dog` model.

I've also used `<form:options>` to fill the select with all the options available for the `breed` attribute.

The `<form:select>` is smart, and if it's working on a populated model (i.e a `Dog` fetched from the database or with default breed value) - it will automatically select the "right" option from the list.

In this case, the controller will look similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveDog")
public String saveDog(@ModelAttribute("myDog") Dog dogFromForm){
    //dogFromForm.getBreed() will give you the selected breed from the <form:select
...
//do stuff
...
}
```

I hope my answer gave you a general idea.