# Spring MVC Combobox Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to add combobox to my form. But in the combobox, instead of names, something else appears.(like com.project.model.stadium@10921021)
[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpRt4.png)

Here are my source codes...

My Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/tribunekle")
public String addTribune(Model model){
    Tribune tribune = new Tribune();
    List<Stadium> stadiumList = stadiumService.getAllStadiums();
    model.addAttribute("tribune",tribune);
    model.addAttribute("stadiumList",stadiumList);

    return "tribunekle";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/tribunekle",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTribunePost(@ModelAttribute("tribune")Tribune tribune, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "tribunekle";
    }
    tribuneService.addTribune(tribune);
    return "redirect:/admin/tribunler";
}
```

Add Tribune JSP:

```js
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@include file="template/adminheader.jsp"%>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Add tribune>
        <p>Yeni tribun ekleyin</p>
    </div>

    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/tribunler/tribunekle" method="POST" commandName="tribune">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tribune Name</label><form:errors path="tribuneName" css="color:#ff0000"/>
            <form:input path="tribuneName" id="name" class="form-Control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stadium">Stadium</label>
            <form:select path="stadium" items="${stadiumList}"/>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
        <a href="<c:url value="/admin/tribunler"/>" class="btn btn-default">Iptal</a>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Tribune class:

```
public class Tribune implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8200937968701786490L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int tribuneId;
@NotEmpty(message = "Tribune name must not be null")
private String tribuneName;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stadiumId")
@JsonIgnore
private Stadium stadium;
```

DaoImpl source codes

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private StadiumService stadiumService;

public void addTribune(Tribune tribune){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(tribune);
    session.flush();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to override the method toString in your class com.project.model.stadium?

Comment: Or take a look at this question about the use of form:select http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860381/what-is-formselect-path-in-spring-tag-used-for

Comment: @RubioRic thank you. Now, stadium names appears in the combobox. But when i click to submit button i get this error;Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.biletdevret.model.Stadium for property stadium; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.biletdevret.model.Stadium] for property stadium: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set itemLabel(which field of Stadium should be placed as label) and itemValue(which field of Stadium should be placed as value) property of form:select tag.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.select

You can also do something like following:

```
<form:select path="stadium">
<c:foreach items=${stadiumList} var="stadium">
   <option value="${stadium.id}">${stadium.name}</option>
</c:foreach>
</form:select>
```

Comment: thank you shi. Now, stadium names appears in the combobox. But when i click to submit button i get this error;Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.biletdevret.model.Stadium for property stadium; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.biletdevret.model.Stadium] for property stadium: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: In your Tribune class you should keep the reference of Stadium not the stadium object itself. In your form combo box as you are selecting stadium id not the stadium itself. Later in your dao layer, you should find stadium from db with selected id and then map stadium object into tribune object to save it.

Comment: Thank you for your response shi . I use JoınColumn annotation in my tribune class. Do i still need to do this operations? I attach my tribune class and daoimpl into the my question

Comment: In that case, in your form:select set path name to stadium.stadiumId or stadium.id whatever the id field is in your stadium object.

Comment: Thank you so muc shi. Now everything is well.